# THE uploading stuck on 0%

Tags: wordpress

I have bought a theme called LMS but once when I upload it..it stuck on 0% in Wordpress and the  Maximum upload for the size of the files: 2 GB.

Answer (score 0):

You will have theme support from the development team who sold it to you. This question is best directed to them via their support.